# Is there any kind of relation between the activity in a website and the hosting that I have to purchase?

Tags: web-hosting, server

Is there any kind of relation between the activity in a website and the server that I have to purchase?

I need to give a budget, for website that could increase the traffic in the future, so I would need to know what type of server should I purchase.

Comment: Short answer. Yes! Your question lacks details and is too general. If you can give use a clue as to what you are doing, that will help. For example some CPU's handle database queries better than others and some CPUs handle web searches better than others. I used to purchase one over the other based upon what the server was to handle.

Comment: @closetnoc Individual advice on purchasing servers is off-topic here since it would only be applicable to that user. There was a catch-all wiki question added early-on for that reason. Suggestions can be asked in the chat room however, where just about anything is game.

Comment: @dan You are right. Did not have my thinking cap on.

Comment: @closetnoc No Worries. Your edit on [this](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61446/what-research-methods-could-i-use-to-determine-the-keywords-i-should-use-for-m) question helped to reopen it, should you want to take a crack at it.

Comment: @dan. Thanks. I was stepping out a bit like you suggested. I like how you edited the question further.